# C++ meaning of [ ]

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

That's from an example of boosts asio.
What does [this] mean? why the []?

```
acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
    [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
```

Comment: It's a [lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11).

Comment: It's part of a [Lambda Expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) used to create a function as an expression

`[]` is the capture list

> A list of symbols can be passed as follows:
>
> - [a,&b] where a is captured by value and b is captured by reference.
> - [this] captures the this pointer by value
> - [&] captures all automatic variables mentioned in the body of the    lambda by reference
> - [=] captures all automatic variables mentioned in the body of the    lambda by value
> - [] captures nothing

Answer (score 4):

It is a part of a lambda expression.  Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for more info.